# Copying CSV File to Excel Using Recorded Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is not working and throwing error

> Invalid Procedure call or argument.

This is the recorded macro code for importing CSV file data into Excel file.

```
Sub CopyCSVtoExcel()
'
' CopyCSVtoExcel Macro
'
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\hkum29\Desktop\New folder\data.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1" _
        ))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierSingleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess, that the file is not existing or there already is a table in `A1`.

Comment: Does it work if you delete the line `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True`?

Comment: No is not working even after deleting line .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True

Comment: Sorry it is `.CommandType = 0` :) Delete that line

Answer (score 0):

As per the MSDN KB [QueryTable.CommandType Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840602(v=office.15).aspx),

> You can set the CommandType property only if the value of the QueryType property for the query table or PivotTable cache is xlOLEDBQuery.

And since it is neither, simply comment the line `.CommandType = 0` or delete that line.